# \uline does not work with \hspace

Tags: ulem

Long story short: Changed laptop and previous working documents don't compile anymore. Problem show up with comamand `\uline` from `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` with argument `\hspace{3cm}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.7in,right=0.8in,top=0.8in,bottom=2in]{geometry} %add  argument to geometry package to see frames [.., showframe..]
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[font=itshape]{quoting}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\uline{all \hfill fine }             %works
\uline{not \hfill fine \hspace{3cm}} %does not work

\end{document}
```

This was working and producing such result:

[image: this is working in a different machine]

Now I am working on a different laptop and got these errors:

```
 !! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\UL@stop ...alty \ifnum \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup\egroup \ifdim \wd \UL@box... \uline{not \hfill fine \hspace{3cm}}
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\UL@stop ...num \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup \egroup\ifdim \wd \UL@box =\z@ \e... \uline{not \hfill fine \hspace{3cm}}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \uline{not \hfill fine \hspace{3cm}}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \uline{not \hfill fine \hspace{3cm}}
```

Miktex is updated, tried with Texstudio and Texmaker, different compilers, I know it should not make difference, but every time blocks here. Sounds something is missing in this laptop. Any idea?

Big thanks.

Comment: If I ignore the errors and open produced pdf, will find the expected results. It makes me even more confused about the errors.

Comment: The \hspace command has been changed. It now supports calc-syntax (if the package calc is used you can do e.g. additions), but this make it fragile for ulem. Put the space in box: `\mbox{\hspace{3cm}}`.

Comment: Perfect, it's compiling without erros once again. Thank you so much. How can I mark your comment as solution?

Comment: Time and time again I see people doing this for completion lines. It would be much easier to fill the line with `\rule[<height>]{<width>}{<thickness>}` or `Name:~\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}`.